# what is the best way to manage pdfs stockage and availabilty?

Tags: laravel, filesystems, backend

we are currently working on a project of restaurants management, we are using laravel/mysql on the backend and we are looking for the best way to manage invoices pdfs , for now we are just storing theme in a public folder but i think this not a prefect way. we think to send the just the order data to frontend and generate the pdf when the user click on a download button but it's still not efficient, so i need an idea to manage pdf invoices and get theme  any time the user wanted them without hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in a database and then retrieving it as well as generating a pdf upon user request is the most efficient way. Saves your storage space and bandwidth. Any other means would be much more consuming.